# spark tasks fail with error, showing exit status: -100

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

The spark job running in yarn mode, shows few tasks failed with following reason:

> ExecutorLostFailure (executor 36 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_xxxxxxxxxx_yyyy_01_000054 on host: ip-xxx-yy-zzz-zz. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

There are two main reasons.

1. It is may because of your memoryOverhead needed by the yarn container is not enough, and the solution is to Increase the `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`
2. Possibly, it is because the slave node disk lack space to write tmp data required by spark. check your yarn usercache dir (for EMR, it locates on `/mnt/yarn/usercache/`),
   or type `df -h` to check your disk remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

Container killed by the framework, either due to being released by the application or being 'lost' due to node failures etc. have a special exit code of -100.
The node failure could be because of not having enough disc space or executor memory.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your cluster is not on AWS but as AWS manager the MR cluster they have released an FAQ

For Glue job: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/container-released-lost-node-100-glue/

For EMR: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-exit-status-100-lost-node/